# Focus back issue in openedge application when closing calling dialog from calling program

Tags: openedge

Issue is related to not getting back the focus to the progress application after closing the dialog screen using .cls programs and last accessed application is sitting on top. As I have tried all the option like , getting the frame handle, processid of application and browser handle for make the progress app on top after closing the child window.

I have tried the below methods for this issue:

Senerio 1
  Used handle of the selected program and apply entry to window.
  Steps used to achive this senerio as follows:
  1.) Define CheckMainFrame as PUBLIC STATIC PROPERTY for get and set in TabFolder.cls.
  2.) Setting the program handle in oplauncher.p after calling the selected program .
        FolderForm:CheckMainFrame = hLaunchProc.
  3.) Getting the handle in method CheckWindowClose after closing the dialog and apply entry to window container.

Senerio 2 
  Used handle of the viewer and apply entry to browser.
  Steps used to achive this senerio as follows:
  1.) Define CheckBrowser as PUBLIC STATIC PROPERTY for get and set in TabFolder.cls.
  2.) Setting the browser handle in CreateRenderedBrowsers where its looping throught the folder pages and when its find 
      the browser and getting the bowser handle.
        TabFolderForm:CheckBrowser = hColumn.
  3.) Getting the browser handle in method CheckWindowClose after closing the dialog and apply entry to browser.

Senerio 3
  Used viewer widget handle and applying entry to first field, cursor is getting the focus.
   Steps used to achive this senerio as follows:
   1.) Define CheckViewer as PUBLIC STATIC PROPERTY for get and set in TabFolder.cls.
   2.) Setting the viewer handle in CreateRenderedBrowsers where its looping through the folder pages for viewer 
       widgets and when its find viewer and getting the first widget handle of viewer and setting the handle to 
       public property of viewer.
        TabFolderForm:CheckViewer = hViewerWidget.
   3.) Getting the Viewer handle in method CheckWindowClose after closing the dialog and apply entry to Viewer.

Senerio 4
   Used process id of the application and apply back focus to the application.
   Steps used to achive this senerio as follows:
   1.) Defined  a method GetCurrentProcessId in Win32.cls program to ge the process id of application .
   2.) Windows.API.Win32:GetCurrentProcessId(OUTPUT ProcessId).
      Getting the processid in method CheckWindowClose after closing the dialog and called the method 
       THIS-OBJECT:MouseClick(ProcessId).
      Forcing Mouse click events as some example below: 
       Windows.API.Win32:PostMessage(hWidget,
                                               Windows.API.WinUser:WM_SETFOCUS,
                                               0,
                                               0) . 
       Windows.API.Win32:PostMessage(hWidget,
                                               Windows.API.WinUser:WM_SETCURSOR,
                                               0,
                                               0) .
       Windows.API.Win32:PostMessage(hWidget,
                                               .Windows.API.WinUser:WM_MDIRESTORE,
                                               0,
                                               0) .

Can anyone suggest me on this?

Comment: Looks like you are using the WinKit. Please indicate your OpenEdge release - as Progress has improved focus management between .NET GUI and ABL GUI largely in every release. Please also indicate the version of the WinKit you are using.

Comment: Got the resolution after lot of research, we can use dll to get the focus of the progress application.